# Add Text in Statusbar [iOS Cydia App]

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, jailbreak, cydia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding view on StatusBar in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833724/adding-view-on-statusbar-in-iphone)

I want to make a Cydia app for iOS. Can anyone tell me how can I add text in the statusbar near the battery icon?

Comment: Imho some googling would help you lot faster and easier. Even here on StackOverflo you cand find the answer you need:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833724/adding-view-on-statusbar-in-iphone

Comment: If that isn't a duplicate then you need to expand your question and show us what you tried, our community isn't intended to be used to write all your code for you. Thanks.