# Custom Icons on Iphone Status Bar

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, icons, statusbar

This could be simple but I haven't found specific information about that. It is possible in monotouch to put a custom icon in the iPhone Status Bar for an specific application? Or this shouldn't be done. I read some information about changing the color or hide the Status Bar but nothing about adding custom icons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no public API for adding icons to the status bar, and doing so using an undocumented method will almost certainly keep you out of the app store.

Answer (score 2):

You can control the [colour](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/user-interface/set-status-bar-color-and-background.html) and some icons (e.g. [network](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html) activity) but it cannot be customized. Also Apple wants you to replace it with your [custom](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html) one.

The only tools (that I know) doing this kind of stuff are for jail-broken phones.

Answer (score 1):

you should refer the below SO link.Its similar to your question Hope it helps you...

1. [Adding view on StatusBar in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833724/adding-view-on-statusbar-in-iphone)