# Root view controller in a Storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

I'm playing around with a single-window template. I have a classic `MainStoryboard.storyboard` file and I have only 1 view controller (which is an *Initial View Controller* all by default)

What I do is I try to implement the behaviour from this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2834029/1313939) and the Xcode tells me this:

```
Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Here's the piece of code where I create a new `UIWindow`:

```
UIWindow *overlayWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] init];
    overlayWindow = [[ACStatusBarOverlayWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    overlayWindow.hidden = NO;
```

And of course my `appDelegate` starts with this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make your window key and visible by

```
[overlayWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
```

as suggested in the very same example you linked.

**EDIT**

This the code you are using

```
UIWindow *overlayWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] init];
overlayWindow = [[ACStatusBarOverlayWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
overlayWindow.hidden = NO;
```

The first line its useless and potentially it is the one which is causing the warning.
You are creating a `UIWindow` instance and than throwing it away in the next line.

Remove it and just do:

```
UIWindow *overlayWindow = [[ACStatusBarOverlayWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
overlayWindow.hidden = NO;
```

Also you should assign a root view controller to the newly created window, by

```
overlayWindow.rootViewController = self.window.rootViewController;
```

Comment: Oh God, now it gives me an error "Property 'rootViewController' not found on object of type 'ViewController *'" and if I use `overlayWindow.rootViewController = self` it just doesn't work!

Comment: sorry I made a typo. I wanted to write `self.window.rootViewController`

Comment: question: where is the code for presenting the overlay window? So far you're just creating it. EDIT: stupid question, we are taking of UIWindow

Comment: What do you mean by *presenting*? Isn't makeKeyAndVisible is what does that for us?

Comment: Sorry I just realized the question was nonsense. Anyway have you tried my last update?

Comment: Yeah and it doesn't work either. Showing the warning and I never actually managed to get that view displayed. **Ever**.

Comment: Ok then, concerning the warning you simply have to create the window instance after the loading, for instance in the `viewDidAppear` method of your controller. Where are you doing that now?

Comment: You are, where is the code you posted for creating the `UIWindow` located?

Comment: Ah, it's in the viewDidLoad. Even if I put it to viewWillAppear **and** viewDidAppear it changes nothing.

Comment: If you put it in viewWillAppear it does show the warning, still I'm not able to make it visible.

Comment: Me too. When put in the viewDidAppear it shows no warning but the view is invisible. Something's wrong with that rootViewController value

Comment: Well, I did it partially. I had to create a new class and a new UIWindow which had to be (strong, nonatomic). You can take a look at where I am now - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051129/application-windows-are-expected-to-have-a-root-view-controller-conditional-ap