# "Application windows are expected to have a root view controller" conditional appearance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiwindow

I'm writing an app for iPhone using Xcode 4.5 and iOS6. I'm also creating a new `UIWindow` to be able to manage the area of the status bar (to display messages there, etc.)
I'm using storyboards and my `appDelegate` method looks like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    return YES;
}
```

The message *does not appear* in the console when I put it in the method called `viewDidAppear`:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated     {

    if (!window) {
        window = [[SGStatusBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        window.frame = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame];
        window.alpha = 0.5f;

        [self.view.window makeKeyAndVisible]; // has to be main window of app
        window.hidden = NO;
    }  
}
```

The same method, put in the `viewDidLoad` gives a warning in the console:

```
2012-12-27 11:34:20.838 NewApp[433:c07] Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
```

Is this because I've created a new `UIWindow`? Why the difference between those two methods is so big?

And, most importantly, how can I get rid of this warning *while* putting the code in the `viewDidLoad` method?

**EDIT:**

I have encountered the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7525069/1313939), but it's not the way I'd like to solve it (it's actually the way I'm solving it *right now*)

I've tried setting my current ViewController as my window's root view controller by doing this:

```
ViewController *vcB = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
window.rootViewController = vcB;
```

But I keep getting a warning that says:

```
Incompatible pointer types initializing 'ViewController *__strong' with an expression of type 'UIViewController *'
```

Comment: I think its asking you to create a NavigationController and add your first controller as root of your navigationcontroller

Comment: @superGokuN I believe you're wrong. Why would I need a NavigationController in an app with only 1 view? And I don't want *or* need to use one.

Comment: as to the difference try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254697/difference-between-viewdidload-and-viewdidappear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `window.rootViewController` property .

Comment: I solved my problem by creating a new UIViewController and setting window.rootViewController property to it. Thanks for a great idea!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your delegate.h and delegate.m files.

AppDelegate.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) YourViewController *viewController;
```

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[[YourViewcontroller alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourViewcontroller" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Hope it works.

Comment: I'm using storyboards and thus, this piece of code is not needed. Thanks for your help, though.